# How would I play audio in Python 2.6.6 while displaying text?

Tags: python, audio, wav, python-2.6

I am trying to make a program with Python 2.6.6 that displays text while having audio playing in the background. I have only completed some of the text.

```
print "Well here we are again"
print "It’s always such a pleasure"
print "Remember when you tried to kill me twice?"
print "Oh, how we laughed and laughed"
print "Except I wasn’t laughing"
print "Under the circumstances I’ve been shockingly nice."
```

I have a .wav file that I would like to play at the beginning of the program. I would also like the text to play in cue with the music (I would be able to specify when the text displays during the song such as 00:00:02). I assume this would be possible with an audio module of some sort.

Thanks!

Comment: You want your answer take it,
That’s what I’m counting on,
I used to want you dead but,
Now I only want more reputation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I did a similar thing recently and used the `audiere` module

```
import audiere
ds = audiere.open_device()
os = ds.open_array(input, fs)
os.play()
```

This will open the first available audio device, since you're on windows it's probably DirectSound.  `input` is just a numpy array, `fs` is the sampling frequency (since the input is a raw array you'll need to specify that).  `os.play()` is a non-blocking call so you can print your txt or whatever you need to do at the same time, there are other methods to pause/stop etc.  To play other file types I simply converted them to wav first.

Here's how I unpacked the wav file

```
def wave_unpack(fname):
  """
  input: wave filename as string 
  output: left, right, params

  unpacks a wave file and return left and right channels as arrays
  (in case of a mono file, left and right channels will be copies)

  params returns a tuple containing:
  -number of audio channels (1 for mono, 2 for stereo)
  -sample width in bytes
  -sampling frequency in Hz
  -number of audio frames
  -compression type
  -compression name
  """
  import sndhdr, os, wave, struct
  from scipy import array
      assert os.path.isfile(fname), "file location must be valid"
  assert sndhdr.what(fname)[0] == 'wav', "file must have valid header"
  try:
    wav = wave.open(fname)
    params = (nchannels,sampwidth,rate,nframes,comp,compname) = wav.getparams()
    frames = wav.readframes(nframes*nchannels)
  finally:
    wav.close()
  out = struct.unpack_from ("%dh" % nframes*nchannels, frames)
  if nchannels == 2:
    left = array(out[0::2])
    right = array(out[1::2])
  elif nchannels == 1:
    right = left = array(out)
  else:
    assert 0, "number of channels must be 1 or 2"
  return left, right, params
```

So for example to make `input` and `fs` you could go:

```
from scipy import c_
left, right, params = wave_unpack(fn)
fs = params[2]
left_float  =  left.astype('f')/2**15
right_float = right.astype('f')/2**15
stereo = c_[left_float, right_float]
input = mono = stereo.mean(1)
```

This suited me but my requirements were for FFT input, not karaoke :)

I'm sure `audiere` has stereo playback just by giving a 2-dim array.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is the GStreamer for Python.

Check [this](http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/) tutorial, it's a good place to start.

**EDIT:**
In Windows you can use the winsound module from standard library (Whoa! Python has that!) See [winsound](http://docs.python.org/library/winsound.html) docs.

Comment: I'm running Windows and from what I gather GStreamer isn't compatible on it. How would I go about doing this task using tools that come built in to Python or is that not possible?

Answer (score 1):

You may find pygame helpful.

http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html